# flutter build apk, but lib dir is not shrinking?

Tags: flutter, flutter-build

I use this command:

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=debugInfo --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi --no-tree-shake-icons
```

My colleagues and I use the same command to build an APK. But the size difference between the two APKs is 40 MB. Unzip the two APKs and find that the lib directory is both 93 MB in size. But his bag is only 60 MB, my bag is 105 MB, I feel that my bag is not compressed.

What I can do?

I tried

1. use diff command
2. config my gradle

Neither of them works.